# Is there a way to use Djinn to auto-generate Haskell code in Emacs?

Tags: haskell, emacs, ghc, theorem-proving, ghc-mod

Title pretty much says it all. I'm looking for something like this:

```
f :: Int -> Bool -> Int
f = _body
```

Djinn can use theorem proving to generate code for such a function by proving that the type is inhabited.

I'm wondering, is there an existing way to get this functionality from within Emacs? So instead of writing TemplateHaskell in my code, I just run a command on my code and it inserts the generated code?

I have ghc-mod installed, but I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the answer is, but I feel like that would have pretty limited utility. In fact, the code you gave is a good example of where Djinn would likely not be very useful (there's a *huge* number of inhabitants of that type. For a 64-bit `Int` size, I believe it would have `((2^64)^2)^(2^64)` inhabitants if I did my math right). It would mostly be useful for polymorphic types but it doesn't support type classes and I don't think it's been updated in a while.

Comment: Yeah, the example I gave wasn't meant to be practical, more just a syntactic example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the relevant part of Serras [emacs guide](https://github.com/serras/emacs-haskell-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial.md#working-with-holes):

> This is nice, but in some cases ghc-mod can do even more for you: it
>   can write your whole expression! It does so by leveraging the power of
>   Djinn. For example, let's go back to the definition of maybeMap after
>   splitting:
>
> maybeMap Nothing  f = _maybeMap_body
>
> maybeMap (Just x) f = _maybeMap_body
>
> If you press C-c C-a in each of the holes, several options for the
>   code to be written there will be shown, including Nothing in the first
>   case, and Nothing and Just x in the second case. You just need to
>   select the code you want to include from a list, and it will be
>   automatically completed. Note that this functionality becomes very
>   handy when you need to work with expressions involving currying and
>   tupling, because it takes care of obtaining a correctly-typed
>   expression for you.

So, yes using Djinn you can write whole expressions in some cases. I haven't personally used them but it seems to be possible in Emacs.