# Can I “factorize” a type signature?

Tags: haskell, hoogle

Suppose I wanted a function of type `[[a]] -> [[b]] -> [[(a, b)]]`. I'm sure I could figure something out, but chances are, it wouldn't be as clean as, for example,  `zipWith zip`, which also has that type.

Entering this type signature into Hoogle gives me a few functions that fill this role, but they come from the `leancheck` and `extrapolate` packages, which I wouldn't want to drag into my project without a good reason.

Given that you can compute function composition through equational reasoning, I am wondering if there is an inverse to this process: **is there a way that I could “factorize” a complex type signature and reduce it down to its simplest function composition?**

Comment: This sounds a bit like djinn: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn

Comment: Surely the **simplest** would be `\_ _ -> []`. This objection may feel silly to you, but it is a serious one: `zipWith zip` is by no means the obvious, canonical, only sensible function of this type. I can think of at least two other quite sensible and useful ones besides this silly, unuseful one (and myriad other silly, unuseful ones).

Comment: I really can't follow what you mean by "factorise" a type signature. The example you give has nothing to do with making any changes to the type signature, and `zipWith zip` isn't a composition. In any event, composition combines (function) *values*, not types.

Comment: @RobinZigmond: based on the question, I think the OP wants to automatically generate functions, based on type signatures.

Comment: There are many functions of this type, the ones you've found in existing packages are not related to `zipWith zip`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you for your comment. Willem Van Onsem had it right, I think the package he pointed at was what I wanted. It's just too bad it has no documentation.

Comment: (...and if djinn is up your alley, see also [exference](https://github.com/lspitzner/exference); unlike djinn, it can handle recursive types like lists, though at the cost that it may not terminate if you ask it a really hard one.)

Comment: @DanielWagner I think the reason I hadn't thought of that is probably the same reason I don't suspect a library function will return `undefined`, even though it would typecheck: I was thinking of non-trivial implementations. Cheers for your objection, though. I will also look into `exference`.

Comment: Also my toy project [djest](https://github.com/luqui/djest) may be up your alley.  It generates functions of a given type signature and looks for ones that pass a test you give it.  E.g. `length (f xs ys) == min (length xs) (length ys)` might find yours. (I really need to clean it up for usability though.)

Comment: There are types for which the question of whether or not values exist is undecidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to DanielWagner and Willem Van Onsem, who answered my question in the comments. What I thought was some sort of category-theory factorization turned out to simply be code generation.

The package [exference](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/exference) does just what I wanted. From the documentation:

> Type inference takes an expression and tells you its type. This process can be inversed: We recursively create random expression trees while checking that they -so far- match a given input type. At each step we do the backwards step of the inference algorithm step. If you are lucky, this search yields one or more expressions.

---

The package [djinn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn) also does code generation from type expressions, but supports less types, and has [little](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/djinn.1.html) [documentation](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1178). However, it is guaranteed to always terminate, unlike exference.

For emacs users, it seems that [djinn is already integrated into ghc-mod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386749/is-there-a-way-to-use-djinn-to-auto-generate-haskell-code-in-emacs).

---

There is also [Djest](https://github.com/luqui/djest), by luqui, which is somewhat in between Quickcheck and the previous tools. It allows you to enter a few sets of input and output, for which the program will try and make up a function that satisfies them.

Thanks to all those who contributed and made me discover these packages.